# Plugins for Eclipse/PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, plugins, pydev

I started learning python recently, it seems fun and interesting. After comparing some IDEs, i concluded with Eclipse+PyDev, because i am already familiar with it from Java.

1) Can i use my favorite plugins(FindBugs, Log4E, Metrics) within the PyDev Perspective?

2) Which plugins do you use for python development in this environment?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you accept one of the answers, I will vote this question up.

Answer (score 1):

> Can i use my favorite
>   plugins(FindBugs, Log4E, Metrics)
>   within the PyDev Perspective?

You cannot use any Java-centric plugins from within the PyDev perspective. You will be able to use non-language specific plugins (VCS, etc..) in harmony with PyDev.

If you want a more "first class" editing solution for Python you can try ActiveState's [Komodo editor](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide), or the thinned-out free version, [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit). Both versions support several languages (Python, Perl, Ruby, JavaScript, etc...) and both versions provide many solid editing and code management features. The pay version also includes a very solid Python debugger, as well as tools for generating executables, modules, packages, etc... Of course, you can do any of these things with open source or free Python libraries, but some of the processes can be tricky (ie: creating a stand-alone executable from source that calls upon multiple Python libraries) and Komodo does a good job of keeping it simple.

Answer (score 0):

No, none of those plugins will work for Python; they're all designed exclusively for Java.

To answer your second question, when I was using PyDev the only plugins that I used for Python were version control -- Subclipse, EGit, MercurialEclipse, that kind of stuff. Most all of the plugins won't do anything for PyDev because they're designed around Java.

You'll find quickly that in Eclipse, Python is definitely not a first class citizen.

Comment: Thanks Rafe. Which environment do you use?

Comment: @openV I stopped using PyDev when I realized it was more trouble than it was worth. Now I just use vim on Linux and Notepad++ on Windows. Perfectly fine for Python

Answer (score 0):

> Can i use my favorite plugins(FindBugs, Log4E, Metrics) within the PyDev Perspective?

Not the Java-specific ones (don't know which of the mentioned plugins are for Java). But PyDev includes support for pylint out of the box - pylint can find many style and other problems in your modules, but you may need to tweak its settings (especially ignoring certain verbose style warnings).

> Which plugins do you use for python development in this environment?

Only AnyEdit Tools for stripping whitespace automatically. I don't need any other plugins accompanying PyDev as it already comes with lots of functionality. For example, check *PyDev > Editor > Code Analysis* for some advanced options - I prefer to enable warnings on unused parameters for instance (which can be suppressed by prefixing parameters with `unused_`, very helpful).

Side note: If you're into Django development, you may want to get Aptana instead of Eclipse, because the PyDev developers offer a Django template editor that doesn't work with vanilla Eclipse.